# SOLR why does its state this 'leaderUrl' must be specified without the /replication suffix

Tags: solr

Why when I setup a Solr follower/slave do I get this message in the Solr logs

```
'leaderUrl' must be specified without the /replication suffix
```

This used to work fine in  ersion 7.6 but now in version 8.11.1 it complains. What should the value be if not /replication?

This is the XML snippet in the solrconfig.xml that does the replications

```
<requestHandler name="/replication" class="solr.ReplicationHandler">
      <lst name="slave">
        <str name="leaderUrl">http://solr1:8983/solr/bookings/replication</str>
        <str name="pollInterval">00:00:20</str>
      </lst>
    </requestHandler>
```

[image]

Comment: I think it saying to remove the /replication from the url which is mentioned in the leaderUrl attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to mean the leadUrl, I seemed to be transfixed on the name of the request handler!

So going from this which worked in 7.6

```
<str name="masterUrl">http://solr1:8983/solr/bookings/replication</str>
```

to this which works in 8.11.1

```
<str name="leaderUrl">http://solr1:8983/solr/bookings</str>
```